# True or False? If the limit of $[f(x)-g(x)]$ as x approaches $a = 0$, then the limit of $f(x), g(x)$, as $x$ approaches $a$, are equal.

Tags: calculus, limits

TRUE OF FALSE?
$$\lim_{x\to\alpha}[f(x)-g(x)]=0\implies\lim_{x\to\alpha}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\alpha} g(x)$$

I'm in senior high school and just recently took a test with this as one of the questions. I initially answered true — I mean, it obviously looks too true. Simple distribution and manipulation of terms would easily show $\lim_{x\to\alpha}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\alpha}g(x)$ — but just before submitting, I changed it to false. I got a perfect score, but I do feel uneasy not knowing why my teacher remarked this as false.

Just for context, maybe the counterexample to make this statement false might involve infinities.  When the limit is $+\infty$ or $-\infty$, we simply write is as "does not exist."
Also we only tackle real number. And our limit definition specifies that $\lim_{x\to\alpha}f(x)$ only exists when $\lim_{x\to\alpha^{+}}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\alpha^{-}}f(x)$.

Qn: The actual question looked like this [Here. Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKpMi.jpg)

Comment: Does anyone else think it is a bit of a poorly worded question by the teacher? If someone wrote that, I would probably mark it true; if the limits exist, then, that is a true sentence, and if someone wrote me a sentence like "A > 500" I would not say ""A" does not exist therefore this is false." (If anything, if A does not exist, I would say that that is vacuously true.)

Comment: @E-A, I think that depends on the course and how it was taught. If I had emphasised during the year that limits can only be equal if they exist I would think it was perfectly fair.

Comment: @Peter hm yeah, I guess if it was emphasized that way, I could see it. Thanks for giving a contrary POV. Still feels weird to me though, so OP, I would say don't feel bad about how you answered it; I think it is just bad form to write the limit of something without discussing its existence. (and if you write nothing of it, your readers will potentially assume that the limit exists!)

Comment: @E-A: No! The given statement (in OP's question) is not vacuously true. Consider the statement "If lim f(x) and g(x) exist and are equal then lim f(x)=lim g(x)"$. If lim f(x) or g(x) fails to exist, the aforementioned statement is not true.

Comment: I was wondering what could be the reasons for the statement being false!! And then I read all the comments above and got to know that the trick was actually hidden in the existence of the limits!!! In every circumstances I would have marked that statement as true

Comment: A more general statement would be that in this case the limiting behavior of $f$ is same as that of $g$ as $x\to a$. If $f(x) $ tends to a limit $L$ or diverges to $\infty$ or $-\infty$ or oscillates finitely or infinitely as $x\to a$ then so does $g(x) $. I don't have any issue with notation $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) =\lim_{x\to a} g(x) $ being used to describe this more general scenario.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Right! Limiting behavior will be same but can we write $\lim f(x)=\lim g(x)$ as $x\to a$ if both the limits exist but not finitely? I'm not really sure whether we can. I think that we shouldn't and I say this because infinities also have some sort of size. Infinity for example may refer to may be aleph null or continuum etc.  But that being aside, if it is pre-assumed that $\pm \infty$ represent any kind of infinity in set of extended reals, then there is no harm in writing equal sign and I think that is the case always whenever extended reals set is considered.

Comment: @Koro: In predicate logic, the example sentence you gave would indeed be most likely true if the limits don't exist (F -> F is a true sentence; the issue with your sentence is that the second half of your sentence doesn't mean anything if the limits don't exist.). It is true the same way the sentence: "If there are five unicorns in my backyard, then 3=4" is true.  Anyway, thanks everyone; just wanted to make sure it was not just me who found an issue with the phrasing.

Comment: @E-A: I think you are right. Now that I think more about it, the example sentence I gave earlier will be true vacuously.

Comment: @Koro : I don't see any dangers if the meaning of notation is explained beforehand. But it's more of a personal opinion.

Answer (score 13):

The key is that you can only say two limits are equal if they exist, and the two limits on the RHS cannot be guaranteed to exist with the given information. You are right in suggesting that the answer can involve infinity, but there are finite examples that are badly behaved as well.

Consider the function $f(x)$ where $f(x)=1$ for $x$ rational and $f(x)=0$ for $x$ irrational. It is a well defined function, but has no limit anywhere. If we let $g(x)=f(x)$, then $f(x)-g(x)=0$ everywhere so the limit is zero for every $\alpha$, but $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have no limit no matter what value of $\alpha$ is chosen.

Comment: I see, I see. Thank you for the explanation :)

Answer (score 4):

If atleast one of $\lim f(x)$ or $\lim g(x)$ exists on $\mathbb R$ i.e. exists finitely then the given statement is true.

WLOG let $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)=l$, where $l\in \mathbb R$

Given that: $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-g(x))=0$

So $f(x)=(f(x)-g(x))+g(x)\implies \lim_{x\to a}f(x)=0+l=l=\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)$

However, if you consider $f(x)=[x]$, where $[.]$ is floor function and $g(x)=-\{x\}$, where $\{.\}$ is fractional part function. Indeed we have $\lim _{x\to 0} (f(x)-g(x))=0$ but neither $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)$ exists nor does $\lim_{x\to 0} g(x)$.

**Note:** It is to be noted that even if either of the limits $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ or $\lim_{x\to a} g(x)$ exists on extended reals that is on the set $\mathbb R\cup \{-\infty, \infty\}$, still if $\lim_{x\to a}(f(x)-g(x))=0$
then $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have the same limiting behaviour as $x\to a$. 
For example: Consider $f(x)=x+\frac 1{|x|}, g(x)=\frac 1{|x|}$, then $f(x)-g(x)=x\to 0$ as $x\to 0$. Also, $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=\infty$

Comment: Can you please elaborate why $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0}g(x)=\infty$? I see that $\lim_{x\to 0^-}f(x)=-1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=\infty$ and so for $g(x)$

Comment: @ManjoyDas: Are you referring to $f,g$ as mentioned in "Note"?

Comment: yes your example in the note section

Comment: @ManjoyDas: Please note that $|.|$ is absolute value function.

Comment: ok thank you. I thought that was the floor function. It is quite dizzy on my screen.

Comment: I see, thank youu :))

Answer (score 1):

What about $\alpha =0$ and
$$f(x)=1+\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \text{ and } g(x)= \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$$

as a counterexample? *If you want $f,g$ to be defined at $0$ just set $f(0)=g(0)=0$.*

If you suppose either $f$ or $g$ to have a limit at $\alpha$, then the result becomes true.

Comment: It doesn't really specify that $f$ and $g$ must have a limit at $\alpha$. Thank you for the answer :))

Comment: In your example, $\lim_{x\rightarrow \alpha}[f(x) - g(x)] = 1$, which is not a proper counterexample. Could just define $f(x) = g(x) = \sin\left(1/x\right)$.

Comment: $x$ instead of $1$ would also do. Either way this was the first answer I saw and it did give me the idea of a counterexample. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Take $f=g$ to be any function that does not have a limit at $\alpha$, for example $\tan x$ at $\alpha=\frac\pi2$.

Comment: Ahh I see, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Start from a simple case in which this is true:
$$ f=x, \quad g=0 $$ when $ \alpha \to 0 $.

We do have the limit $$ \lim_{\alpha \to 0} f(x)-g(x)=0 $$

For any situation similar to this, I can simply plus a so-called "pathological" term to both $f$ and $g$ to make their limits at $0$ *do not exist*

$$ f=x+\sin \frac{1}{x}, \quad g=\sin \frac{1}{x} $$

or

$$ f=x+e^{\frac{1}{x}}\sin \frac{1}{x^2}, \quad g=e^{\frac{1}{x}}\sin \frac{1}{x^2} $$
Thus our counterexamples do not have to be infinity cases.
Hope this would help.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much :))

Comment: It should say "when $\alpha = 0$" and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \alpha}[f(x) - g(x)] = 0$.